# swift, Tableview is displayed incorrectly after saving new Data

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

at first sorry for my bad english.

My problem is that my tableview will be misrepresented as soon as I save a new file in Firebase.

When saving, a new AddViewController is called.
After saving is automatically returned to the TableviewController.
However, if I stop and restart the app so that the TableviewController is recreated, my tableview will be displayed correctly.

I create a header from an array.
Then I create the cell from another array.

I do not understand why my tableview is displayed incorrectly when I return after saving, but when I recreate the view after the app has finished everything is shown correctly.

My sample pictures:

that's right:

[image: right]

that's bad

[image: bad]

My Code from TableViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TagebuchViewController.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refresher)
    loadTableview()
}
```

Load data from Firebase, loadTableView():

```
func loadTableview(){

    let userID = Firebase.Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("DiabetesIOS").child(userID!)
    databaseRef.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

        var newItems = [Post]()
        var newItemsDate = [String]()

        var aNewTime = [String]()
        var aNewBl = [String]()
        var aNewK = [String]()
        var aNewBo = [String]()
        var aNewBa = [String]()
        var aNewBlu = [String]()
        var aNewP = [String]()
        var aNewN = [String]()

        var dimArrayNewTime = [[String]]()
        var dimArrayNewBl = [[String]]()
        var dimArrayNewK = [[String]]()
        var dimArrayNewBo = [[String]]()
        var dimArrayNewBa = [[String]]()
        var dimArrayNewBlu = [[String]]()
        var dimArrayNewP = [[String]]()
        var dimArrayNewN = [[String]]()

        for year in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            for month in year.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                for day in month.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    for date in day.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                        for time in date.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                            let newPost = Post(snapshot: time)
                            newItems.append(newPost)

                            let newDate = Post(snapshot: time)
                            newItemsDate.append(newDate.snap6Date!)

                            if self.snapshotCheck == 0{
                                self.snapshotCheckDate = newDate.snap6Date
                                self.snapshotCheck += 1
                            }
                            else{
                            }

                            if self.snapshotCheckDate == newDate.snap6Date{
                                aNewTime.append(newDate.time)
                                aNewBl.append(newDate.blutzucker)
                                aNewKe.append(newDate.ke)
                                aNewBo.append(newDate.bolusInsulin)
                                aNewBa.append(newDate.basalInsulin)
                                aNewBlu.append(newDate.blutdruck)
                                aNewP.append(newDate.puls)
                                aNewN.append(newDate.notiz)

                            }
                            else{
                                dimArrayNewTime.append(aNewTime)
                                dimArrayNewBl.append(aNewBlutzucker)
                                dimArrayNewK.append(aNewKe)
                                dimArrayNewBo.append(aNewBolusinsulin)
                                dimArrayNewBa.append(aNewBasalinsulin)
                                dimArrayNewBlu.append(aNewBlutdruck)
                                dimArrayNewP.append(aNewPuls)
                                dimArrayNewN.append(aNewNotiz)

                                aNewTime.removeAll()
                                aNewBl.removeAll()
                                aNewK.removeAll()
                                aNewBo.removeAll()
                                aNewBa.removeAll()
                                aNewBlu.removeAll()
                                aNewP.removeAll()
                                aNewN.removeAll()

                                aNewTime.append(newDate.time)
                                aNewBl.append(newDate.blutzucker)
                                aNewK.append(newDate.ke)
                                aNewBo.append(newDate.bolusInsulin)
                                aNewBa.append(newDate.basalInsulin)
                                aNewBlu.append(newDate.blutdruck)
                                aNewP.append(newDate.puls)
                                aNewN.append(newDate.notiz)

                                self.snapshotCheckDate = newDate.snap6Date
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.postArrayValue = newItems

        self.aHeaderDate = newItemsDate
        self.aHeaderDate = self.uniq(source: self.aHeaderDate) 

        dimArrayNewTime.append(aNewTime)
        dimArrayNewBl.append(aNewBl)
        dimArrayNewK.append(aNewK)
        dimArrayNewBo.append(aNewBo)
        dimArrayNewBa.append(aNewBa)
        dimArrayNewBlu.append(aNewBlu)
        dimArrayNewP.append(aNewP)
        dimArrayNewN.append(aNewN)

        self.dimArrayTime = dimArrayNewTime
        self.dimArrayBl = dimArrayNewBl
        self.dimArrayK = dimArrayNewK
        self.dimArrayBo = dimArrayNewBo
        self.dimArrayBa = dimArrayNewBa
        self.dimArrayBlu = dimArrayNewBlu
        self.dimArrayP = dimArrayNewP
        self.dimArrayN = dimArrayNewN


        newItems.removeAll()
        newItemsDate.removeAll()

        aNewTime.removeAll()
        aNewBl.removeAll()
        aNewK.removeAll()
        aNewBo.removeAll()
        aNewBa.removeAll()
        aNewBlu.removeAll()
        aNewP.removeAll()
        aNewN.removeAll()

        dimArrayNewTime.removeAll()
        dimArrayNewBl.removeAll()
        dimArrayNewK.removeAll()
        dimArrayNewBo.removeAll()
        dimArrayNewBa.removeAll()
        dimArrayNewBlu.removeAll()
        dimArrayNewP.removeAll()
        dimArrayNewN.removeAll()

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }){
        (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }   
}
```

For my Header:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell1
    headerView.date.text = aHeaderDate[section]
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return headerView
}
```

NumberOfRows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dimArrayTime[section].count

}
```

Number of Headers:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return aHeaderDate.count
}
```

Number of Cells:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dimArrayTime[section].count

}
```

Section:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell2 = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell2", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! TableViewCell2

    let sectionTime = dimArrayTime[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let sectionBl = dimArrayBl[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let sectionK = dimArrayK[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let sectionBo = dimArrayBo[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let sectionBa = dimArrayBa[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let sectionBlu = dimArrayBlu[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let sectionP = dimArrayP[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let sectionN = dimArrayN[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell2.time.text = sectionTime
    cell2.bl.text = sectionBl
    cell2.k.text = sectionK
    cell2.bo.text = sectionBo
    cell2.ba.text = sectionBa
    cell2.blu.text = sectionBlu
    cell2.p.text = sectionP
    cell2.n.text = sectionN

    return cell2

}
```

addViewController:

```
@IBAction func saveInDatabaseFirebase(_ sender: Any) {

    let userID = Firebase.Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let postRef = dataRef.child("DIOS").child(userID!).child(stringForDbYear).child(stringForDbMonth).child(stringForDbDay).child(stringForDbDate).child(stringForDbTime)

    sDate = tFDate.text!

    if tFBl.text == "" {
        sBl = "-"
    }
    else{
        sBl = tFBl.text!
    }
    if tFK.text == "" {
        sK = "-"
    }
    else{
        sK = tFK.text!
    }
    if tFBo.text == "" {
        sBo = "-"
    }
    else{
        sBo = tFBo.text!
    }
    if tFBa.text == "" {
        sBa = "-"
    }
    else{
        sBa = tFBa.text!
    }
    if tfBlu.text == "" {
        sBlu = "-"
    }
    else{
        sBlu = tfBlu.text!
    }
    if tFP.text == "" {
        sP = "-"
    }
    else{
        sP = tFP.text!
    }
    if tFN.text == "" {
        sN = "-"
    }
    else{
        sN = tFN.text!
    }


    let post = Post (date: stringForDbDate, time: stringForDbTime, day: stringForDbDay, bl: sBl, k: sK, bo: sBo, ba: sBa, blu: sBlu, p: sP, n: sN, snap1DIOS: "DIOS", snap2UserID: userID!, snap3Year: stringForDbYear, snap4Month: stringForDbMonth, snap5Day: stringForDbDay, snap6Date: stringForDbDate, snap7Time: stringForDbTime)
    postRef.setValue(post.toAnyObject())

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil); 
}
```

Thank you very much for help

Comment: How do you update your `tableView`? It looks like the data is getting out of order when adding new.

Comment: I update my tableView with self.tableView.reloadData() in the func loadTableview(). I do not understand why is getting out of order when adding new... when I call "self.tableView.reloadData ()" in viewWillAppear, nothing happens

Comment: The issue is your variable you are storing the data in - not the table. When you are retrieving the information from Firebase the first time - everything is correct but when you get it the second time its wrong. There's a lot of extra code here to sift through to find your problem. If you just post the code generating the Headers and the Hello it would be more helpful. Where is the number of headers coming from and where are the number of cells coming from?

Comment: I have update my question

Comment: Where is 'addViewController'? Did you try to clear all the data in your viewDidLoad before you call `loadTableview`. Clear all the arrays and/or dictionaries you are using.

Comment: i have updated my question. I have cleared all the arrays and similar things, in viewDidDisappear. But I tried as you said in viewDidLoad. but it does not work anyway.

Comment: Alright, making more sense now. Last questions before I take a crack at it. What is the problem exactly? The headers are off and the content is shifted by 1? Print out the datasource before and after and post the difference.

Comment: Clear Array Just Before adding new Data. And Compare both old and new Array. And Double Check your refreshing code again. That's seem main reason for this issue.

Comment: I cleaned everything. After saving I have no Section 0 in the array. Befor save new Data: "6:50 PM Section:0 Row:0" and after save new Data: "6:50 PM Section:1 Row:0"

Comment: no one has an idea anymore? please

Comment: I have to mention that the array is simple for the header, and for the sections multidimensional